# How to check if string is in list?

Tags: python

I have got a list of files from a directory and stored the files name into a list. Now I would like to remove from the list any files which contain certain text. I'm having trouble coming up with a way of doing this:

```
import os

StartPath = 'C:/PythonScripts/TestDirectory/'
EndPath = 'C:/PythonScripts/TestDirectoryDestination/'


filess = []
MoveFiles = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(StartPath):
    for file in f:
        filess.append(os.path.join(file))

#Remove protected files
for x in range(len(filess)):
    if '.txt' in filess[x]:
        #
        print('eee')
    if 'Copy' in filess[x]:
        #
        print('dd')
    else:   
        MoveFiles.append(filess[x])

#Move Files
for x in range(len(MoveFiles)):
    print(MoveFiles[x])
    if '.txt' in MoveFiles[x]:
        os.rename(StartPath + MoveFiles[x], EndPath + MoveFiles[x])
```

Now the idea if I would go through the first list and use if to check if the text was in the filename and then if it was not I would add it to a second list, this list I would use to move the files.

Now this would work, but it seems wrong. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `if '.txt' in filess[x]:` you're ignoring the files with that and then again  `if '.txt' in MoveFiles[x]:` youre trying to move the same files which have the `.txt` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to make all those lists:

```
import shutil
search_text = 'someSearchText'
for r, d, f in os.walk(StartPath):
    for file in f:
        if search_text not in file:
            shutil.move(StartPath, EndPath)
```

**EDIT**:

For a list of search_items:

```
search_text_lst = ['someSearchText1', 'someSearchText2']

for search_text in search_text_lst:
    if search_text not in file:
        shutil.move(StartPath, EndPath)
```

Comment: Hi DirtyBit, thanks for this. However I can't get it to work with a List of search_terms. The if works with a single search term.

Comment: @EdwardBennett edited the answer with a list approach.